# python regular expression to match anything not containing some word, in between 2 characters

Tags: python, regex

In Fortran, a data statement begins with the word "data", followed by the name of the array, then followed by the values of the array, sandwiched between two forward slashes "/".

```
pattern_data = r'''
( data [^/]+ / [^/]+ / )
'''

c = "data plevel = /4.56, 234., 1e-45/ data tlayer / -5.6, +290.098/"
```

In the above, `c` is like a sample Fortran code containing 2 data statements which I want to extract.  `pattern_data` is the regular expression that matches any sub-string that starts with "data", followed any character other than "/", followed by "/", followed by anything other than "/", followed by "/".

This seems to work, giving:

```
regex = re.compile(pattern_data, re.VERBOSE)

regex.findall(c)
['data plevel = /4.56, 234., 1e-45/', 'data tlayer / -5.6, +290.098/']
```

But what if I wanted to say instead: "data", followed by anything other than "/", followed by "/", followed by anything other than "data", followed by "/".  I think this would also match a data statement, but what is the regular expression for 'anything other than "data"'?

I have tried using a negative lookbehind like this:

```
data [^/]+ / (?<! data).* /
```

But this matches the entire string `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt would prohibit `data` being immediately before the first slash, which is not what you want. This tests whether `data` is anywhere between the slashes:

```
( data [^/]+ /  (?! [^/]* data )  [^/]+ / )
```

Comment: Is it not possible to not have "[^/]" between the two "/"s?

Comment: The lookahead needs to be bounded as well. With `/ (?! .*? data) .*? /`, you would disqualify `/1, 2, 3/ data` (because lookahead will not stop where the match stops).